# Create string based on characters expected

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to create a string based on the number of characters passed in. Each character passed in will be a "X". So for example, if the length passed in is 5, then the string created should be

```
NSString *testString=@"XXXXX";
```

if it is 2 then it would be

```
NSString *testString=@"XX";
```

Can anyone tell me what the most efficient way to do this would be?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the maximum length is some reasonable number then you could do something simple like this:

```
- (NSString *)xString:(NSUInteger)length {
    static NSString *xs = @"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    return [xs substringToIndex:length];
}


NSString *str = [self xString:5]; // str will be @"XXXXX";
```

If you pass in too large of a length, the app will crash - add more `X`s to `xs`.

This approach is more efficient than building up an `NSMutableString` but it does make an assumption about the maximum length you might need.

Comment: I like that solution! Nice little hack. Thank you!

Comment: Nice thinking. As it is likely most use cases would not need something so large. Although the single NSMutableString isn't that much overhead when you consider the number of objects present in an app just to run and unedited project template.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (NSString *)stringOf:(NSString *)str times:(NSInteger)count
{
    NSMutableString *targ = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:count];
    for (int i=0; i < count; i++)
    {
        [targ appendString:str];
    }
    return targ;
}
```

and

```
[self stringOf:@"X" times:4];
```

note that `initWithCapacity:` (in performance manner) better than init. But I guess that's all for efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is

```
NSMutableString *xString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
while ( int i = 0; i < testString.length; i++ ) {
    [xString appendString:@"X"];
    i++;
}
```

Comment: I would prefer using `initWithCapacity:` rather than `init` just for performance point of view

Answer (score 1):

NSUInteger aLength. // assume this is the argument

NSMutableString *xStr = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: aLength];

for ( NSUInteger i = 0; i < aLength; i++ ) {
   [xStr appendFormat:@"X"];
}

Answer (score 1):

The following will do what you ask in one call:

```
NSString *result = [@"" stringByPaddingToLength:numberOfCharsWanted
                                     withString:characterToRepeat
                                startingAtIndex:0];
```

where `numberOfCharsWanted` is an `NSUInteger` and `characterToRepeat` is an `NSString` containing the character.